# French characters are converted to garbage while getting from UI

Tags: websphere-portal

I have a simple portlet application on websphere portal server. On the UI (jsp), there is a text area where user enters some french text and then the portlet gets it and updates to DB.
I enter the French characters by copying from an excel sheet(not through keyboard). But when I save it, the French characters are converted to garabge and saved to DB.

What are some things I should check? This happens only in one environment. In another environment, things run fine. (i.e.French characters are proper)
EDIT: Thank you for the answers. I checked that the data is sent correctly from the browser. Also when I deploy the portlet front end locally and use the back end for SIT, it works fine. But when both the portlet and the back end are SIT, it gives the problem.

Comment: Check the character encoding is UTF-8 in all places where Strings are used.

Comment: I checked the encoding in browser. It is UTF 8. Where else should I check? Can you please elaborate on this:'in all places where Strings are used.'? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that data is sent properly from the browser. For that you can use Firbug to inspect the `POST` data.
Once you make sure that the information is sent properly,you need to verify how the data on server side.
Assume that you are getting the data from the client in `processAction()` method. Verify that data from the request is in the correct format. You may have to set the encoding in the `ActionRequest` as `UTF-8`. Once you have the data in the correct format you need to verify the encoding which is used in Database.